# API Gateway Proxy for S3 with subdirectories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, api-gateway

I created an API Gateway method GET with integration type "AWS Service" for "S3". 
I defined a Path override: {object} that is mapped from method.request.path.item

[image: Integration Request]

As long as the path contains only the bucket itself (./bucket/**mybucketname**), it works and the value of {item} is **mybucketname**.

But when i specify for example ../bucket/**mybucketname/foo/bar/test.txt** as path the {item} value should be mybucketname/foo/bar/test.txt but it is **empty**. I think it's because of the nested path

When i choose catch-all path variables {proxy+} I'm not able to choose integration type "AWS Service" any longer.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong or what i should do in order to retrieve files/folders in subfolders from S3 via API Gateway?

Comment: did you solve it? It would be great if you can post the answer. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 19):

This can be done using [proxy resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/apigateway/proxy-resource).

Here are my steps to achieve what @Johnny90 wants:

1. Click on your API in the API Gateway console.
2. Choose the `/bucket` resource and then choose *Create Resource* from the *Actions* drop-down menu. Then, do the following in the New Child Resource pane.

   a. Tick "Configure as proxy resource".

   b. Use the default `proxy` for Resource Name.

   c. Use `{proxy+}` for Resource Path.

   d. Choose *Create Resource*.
3. Choose HTTP Proxy for Integration type and type the Endpoint URL as any website (e.g., https://my-website.com/{proxy} ). Then choose *Save*.
4. Choose *Integration Request*

   a. Select *AWS Service* as the Integration type.

   b. From the AWS Region drop-down list, choose the region that your S3 bucket resides in.

   c. From AWS Service, choose S3. For AWS Subdomain, leave it blank.

   d. For HTTP method, choose GET.

   e. Choose *Use path override* for *Action Type*. and type `bucket/{proxy}`.

   f. Paste an IAM role that has enough permissions.

   g. Click *Save*.

After changing the integration request from *HTTP Proxy* integration to *AWS Service*, we have to add some settings for the API. First, you must set up the URL Path Parameters so that API Gateway can understand the `{proxy}` variable defined in *resource path* in *Integration Request*.

1. Extend *URL Path Parameters* in Integration Request and then choose *Add path*.
2. Type `proxy` in the Name column and `method.request.path.proxy` in the *Mapped from* column.

Second, choose *Method Response* from *Method Execution*.

1. Choose Add Response. Type 200 for HTTP status.
2. Expand the response of the 200 code.

   a. Choose *Add Header*. Type `Content-Type` for the Name.

   b. Click *Add Response Model*. Type `application/json` for `Content type` and choose *Empty* from the Models drop-down menu.

Finally, choose *Integration Response* from *Method Execution*.

1. Extend the 200 Method response status
2. For *Header Mapping*, you should see the *Content-Type* in the Response header column. Type `integration.response.header.Content-Type` in the *Mapping value* column.

The following are my configurations:

Integration Request:
[image]

Integration Response:
[image]

Method Response:
[image]

Comment: It's not working when you call file from invoked url. 
the exact error message is:
Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to base64 decode the body.

Comment: @Brian Can you please explain what to put in TEST section of API GATEWAY ?

Answer (score 7):

The key is how you pass the value for {object} variable in Path Override. 
I think you set url path parameter for integration request from request path, like this:

```
object = method.request.path.object
```

I believe the problem was because the object has "/" in it, so does the api path (resource).
It cause the api gateway can only recognized object in root path.

What I do is set url path parameter for integration request from request querystring like this:

```
object = method.request.querystring.object
```

It works

Or you can try encode the object path using url encode, replace '/' with '%2F'. I never tried though.

Comment: URL Encoding your ObjectIds to replace '/' with '%2F' works too

Comment: @KevinHooke don't suppose you remember how you did this?

Comment: @Samuurai I think it was with URLEncoder.encode() / decode()

Answer (score 4):

@johnny90, First configure as lambda proxy while creating resource {proxy+}...After creating..update integration type as "AWS Service".Then you can configure any AWS service to your API gateway.

Comment: This one is working an should be the accepted answer! Using the proxy resource avoids URL encoding issues when accessing S3 subdirectories.

Comment: I'm not able to set the integration type as "AWS Service" after creating resource {proxy+}.

Answer (score 4):

Path override : bucket_name/{folder} pattern as per level, it's for first {folder}.

[image]

you can access s3 nested path like this.
[image]

this is for last {object}, so mentioned all path map.
this link will helpfull
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Answer (score 2):

You might use "%2F" as path separator in your requesting URL, e.g.:

`foo%2Fbar` in the URL will be translated into `foo/bar` S3 path.

Comment: WoW! This one should be the accepted answer! Easy!