# Serve Static HTML Pages + Assets w/ Expiration but serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to serve static HTML Pages w/ multiple assets (html, css, js & other asset files) but with different conditions:

- Serverless (must be on S3)
- Can handle multiple static Pages w/ multiple pages and other static assets like css, js, image or font files. (see example below)
- Has an expiration - The goal is the user cannot share the limited-time URL of the static HTML page

Below are all my ideas (correct me if I'm wrong):

- Render directly on Web level - Web support rendering of a specific asset but cannot create a new page for loading all assets
- Serve on S3 level - The question is how can you **authorize** users w/ **limited-time access** to multiple files?

  - Presigned URL? - A pre-signed URL is valid for only one object.
- Store on S3 bucket and Serve on CloudFront - Same question on S3 level. How can you **authorize** users w/ **limited-time access** to multiple files?
- Serve on S3 level publicly - Every time user requests access, copy all files to a new public folder w/ expiration, serve publicly and give the new URL to the user.

  - maybe slow? maybe costly?

```
  #example file structure
  .
  +-- index.html
  +-- media
  |   +-- banner.jpg
  |   +-- video.mp4
  +-- styles
  |   +-- main.css
  +-- js
  |   +-- main.js
  +-- about.html
  +-- contact.html
```

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is serve the S3 Bucket via API Gateway. The expiration and authorization will be handled on the API Gateway side. Please see the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

To handle subdirectories, you can follow the instruction here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60336354/6455686